# How can I go through several possibilities without exhausting loops?

Tags: java

> How can I go through several possibilities without exhausting loops in a program that sum of the proper divisors(divisors including 1 but not itself) of the number is greater than the number, but no subset of those divisors sums to the number itself.

For Example:

12=(factors sum)1+2+3+4+6

Atleast Any Subset Sum should be equal to the number i.e 12 in this case.

Question link
:http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=301

Approach:

Step1 (Doubt)

By looking at the problem I found that its optimal solution will be Dynamic Programming.(Since I don't know that).

Apart from that I thought of the solution like this

For Example 12=1,2,3,4,6(divisors)

So,Solving it through like this with 1 starting having all permutations: 1+2+3+4+6 or 1+3+4+6 or 1+4+6 or 1+6(checking at each step whether it is <=12.

Similarly,I checked starting with 2: 2+3+4+6 or 2+4+6(I got and moved out of the loop)

The solution I am thinking here is very long.I have to put seperate loop for each number and also I am saving the divisors in a string.

> Can anyone give me "Hint" how to start the problem without the Dynamic Programming(Dp)  approach as I am learning Dp these days.

Comment: Maybe you can shorten your question to: "How can I go through several possibilities without exhausting loops?" And the answer would be:"recursion!".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a method

```
int[] getDivisors(int number)
```

the hard task here is to evaluate the possible sums.
An easy but long way would be, to iterate over all of those like that.
Think of such a sum as a binary code, 1 if its in sum, 0 if its not.
Now you can write a for-loop which, from 0...0 to 1...1 (in binary) with #1s = divisors.length;
Maybe a better way would be recursion methods. Like:

```
boolean hasSameSum(int number, Stack<Integer> divisors, int sum){
    if(sum==number)
         return false;
    if(divisors.isEmpty())
         return true;
    int div = divisor.pop();
    return hasSameSum(number, divisors, sum)&&hasSameSum(number, divisors, sum+div);
}
```

But honestly, that's not a programming problem, but more a mathematical approach problem :-)

Comment: So many negative votes.That's Wierd for a Wierd Problem.Is there anything I can do to understand the question better?I haven't written the code for the problem because of the large complexity and I was thinking of a HINT to solve this problem.

Comment: it's because most people here only like to answer for programming problems and not logical ones. In this case i would suggest you to try recursion methods (like in edit). This one i am not sure if it solves your problem, but in pathfinding problems, like yours, they are mostly the better choice.